# How to create a pipeline on a field that contains dots with ElasticSearch (w/ no script)

Tags: elasticsearch

We prefer to use no script in our pipeline because with no script the pipeline can reach QPS of 10000+, whilst added the scripts it drops to 3000+.

When I use `/_ingest/pipeline/user_agent` to create a pipeline as such:

```
{
    "description": "Add user agent information",
    "processors": [
        {
            "user_agent": {
                "field": "meta.http.headers.user-agent",
                "ignore_missing": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I really want is to allow the pipeline to process data below:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "http.headers.user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 MicroMessenger/8.0.2(0x1800022c) NetType/WIFI Language/zh_CN"
    }
}
```

I also tried to create pipeline as below:

```
{
    "description": "Add user agent information",
    "processors": [
        {
            "user_agent": {
                "field": "meta.http\\.headers\\.user-agent",
                "ignore_missing": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

OR

```
{
    "description": "Add user agent information",
    "processors": [
        {
            "user_agent": {
                "field": "[meta][http.headers.user-agent]",
                "ignore_missing": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

They wouldn't work.

When I have pipeline as such:

```
{
    "description": "Add user agent information",
    "processors": [
        {
            "user_agent": {
                "field": "meta.user-agent",
                "ignore_missing": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Whilst the data is

```
{
    "meta": {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 MicroMessenger/8.0.2(0x1800022c) NetType/WIFI Language/zh_CN"
    }
}
```

It works.

Unfortunately our architecture has already set-up to produce data like

```
{
    "meta": {
        "http.headers.user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 MicroMessenger/8.0.2(0x1800022c) NetType/WIFI Language/zh_CN"
    }
}
```

It's pretty much impossible to update all of our apps and services to change the data structure at this point... :frowning: So is it possible to support

```
{
    "meta": {
        "http.headers.user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 MicroMessenger/8.0.2(0x1800022c) NetType/WIFI Language/zh_CN"
    }
}
```

and how?

P.S. The below method almost work but I am not able to change the expanded field back to `http.headers.user-agent`.

```
{
    "description": "Add user agent information",
    "processors": [
        {
            "dot_expander": {
                "field": "http.headers.user-agent",
                "path": "meta"
            }
        },
        {
            "user_agent": {
                "field": "meta.http.headers.user-agent",
                "ignore_missing": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is to use the [`dot_expander` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dot-expand-processor.html) just before the `user-agent` processor, like this:

```
{
    "description": "Add user agent information",
    "processors": [
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "meta2",
          "copy_from": "meta"
        }
      },
      {
        "dot_expander": {
          "field": "http.headers.user-agent",
          "path": "meta2"
        }
      },
      {
        "user_agent": {
          "field": "meta2.http.headers.user-agent",
          "ignore_missing": true
        }
      },
      {
        "remove": {
          "field": ["meta2"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work as expected. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it out

Comment: Well script is not exactly efficient that's why I didn't use it to begin with, otherwise I could have just use script without the help of dot_expander, user_agent, and remove...

Comment: When the data design is not efficient (read flawed) in the first place, it's usually when you have to resort to less efficient data processing down the way...

Comment: Also, what makes you think that it's not efficient (any benchmark)? You can store the script so it's compiled only once and then refer to it by id, and it will run very fast. Scripting in the context of an ingest processor is way less problematic than in the context of a search query or an aggregation, because all documents MUST go through the pipeline anyway. You should try, benchmark and only then seek to optimize if you witness a real problem, but not based on assumptions that having one line of scripting is inefficient

Comment: Also, you should have stated in your question that a script processor was no go for you, it would have helped save time for people searching for a solution ;-)

Comment: With no script the pipeline can reach QPS of 10000+, whilst added the scripted pipeline you have provided it drops to 3000+.

Comment: Did you store the script instead of using it inline?

Comment: It's actually the same. No improvement found,

Comment: @AeroWang: Did you find a solution? Asking because I have the exact same problem :)

Comment: @Jabez I've modified my answer with a pipeline that doesn't use any script. Please try it out

Comment: @Jabez turns out it's best to migrate to clickhouse and forget about elasticsearch at this point.